# Limit Ethereum mining difficulty in a private blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, difficulty

I am creating a private Ethereum blockchain for the sake of transactions management and storage. I don't care about the consensus part, so I changed the difficulty in the genesis file to `0x1`.

I also edited the `consensus.go` file located under the `consensus/ethash/` directory, and built a custom geth binary to limit the growth of difficulty but with no luck. Here's what I changed exactly, I changed the `CalcDifficulty()` method implementation with the following:

```
func (ethash *Ethash) CalcDifficulty(chain consensus.ChainReader, time uint64, parent *types.Header) *big.Int {
  return big.NewInt(1)
}
```

The problem is that with every block, the difficulty is increased by one. I tried to change the return value to `return big.NewInt(0)` but I got an error saying `panic: division by zero`

I just want to limit the difficulty to `0x1` regardless of how many blocks the chain has.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a year ago. The easiest solution is to only mine, when there are transaction in the pool. This would only increase the difficulty a little bit and so you have a fast test-network. As far as i know, ganache does exactly this.